# How can i add a script to all children by script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Start()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in ShipParent.transform)
        {
            ShipsChildren.Add(child);

        }
    }
```

I want to add a script to every child.
I know how to do it with GameObject:

```
foreach(GameObject go in waypoints)
          {
              go.AddComponent<SlowDown>();
          }
```

But if it's Transform ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Game Object holding the [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) by using transform.gameObject. So you can do:

```
void Start()
{
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        child.gameObject.AddComponent<SlowDown>();
    }
}
```